# Getting title from WKWebView using evaluateJavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a very simple/easy question but have absolutely zero experience with java. I have a `WKWebView` and I want to get the title text of the page using the javascript `document.getElementById`.

The webpage I am trying to get the title from has this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="toolbar">
<h1 id="pageTitle">Schedules</h1>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

This code is abridged so I apologize for any errors.

Then I am trying to access the pageTitle in Swift with:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pageTitle').value") { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is returning nil. After hours of searching I still have no idea how to get this to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use javascript to retrieve the page title. [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKWebView/title) has a `title` property that will retrieve this for you

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKWebView/title

> `title` The page title. (read-only)
>
> SWIFT 
>   `var title: String? { get }`
>
> The WKWebView class is key-value observing (KVO) compliant for this property.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Comment: Oh I see. This is good to know but there are some other elements on the webpage that I would also like to retrieve. I wanted to get a general understanding of the process so that I may get other details in the future.

Comment: do you have a followup q, because this answer doesn't answer my question, which is the same as yours, but not for title.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @SilkyPantsDan, if you are just interested in the `title`, there's no need to use JS. Firstly you start observing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.title), options: .new, context: nil)
}
```

And handle your logic when `title` is updated:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
if keyPath == "title" {
        title = webView.title
    }
}
```

Finally you should stop observing if you are supporting iOS 8.0, as observers are not removed automatically before iOS 9.0:

```
deinit {
    webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "title")
    //webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in the second block of code above. The second line should be `if keyPath == "title" {`

Answer (score 3):

In your code when there is some error, then the code will print the result. This'll print nothing when there is no error occuer.

So change you code to this, everything works well.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pageTitle').innerHTML") { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Node.textContent to get a correct copy of text nodes contents.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pageTitle').textContent") { (result, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this same code snippet, and worked out the issue... It'll only print the result if it's "nil"!

Try:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pageTitle').textContent") { (result, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: How this help OP in fixing current issue?

Comment: Because there is a good chance the code works, but OP will never see the result! The only output will be "nil"

Answer (score 0):

this code is works for me :

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.title').textContent") { (result, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```