# Swift wkwebview get title returns nothing if title contains 2 or more arabic words

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a weird problem when I call get title from wkwebview. If web title in English it works perfectly but in the title in Arabic and contains 2 or more words it returns nothing. The problem disappears when title contains one Arabic word. any help?

the code I use:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let webTitle:String = webView.title!
    print("Title: \(webTitle)")
    self.title = webTitle
}
```

here are photos that explain the problem

[English Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PI45.jpg)

[One Arabic word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDhDi.jpg)

[Two Arabic words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fPPs.jpg)

---

### TEMPORARY FIX

As @EmilioPelaez said that it seems to be a bug. I fixed this using evaluateJavaScript (Thanks to @the4kman).

The code I used:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let javascript = "document.title\n"

    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.title = String(describing: result!)
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this bug will be fixed soon :)

Comment: I suggest submitting a bug report to Apple https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Seems indeed like a bug. [Try getting the title using evaluateJavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32751629/3151675)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I submitted a bug report as you suggested said and I used evaluateJavaScript to get the title and it worked thanks to you @the4kman